# unable to filter the records using drop down list

Tags: php

filter the record using selected field catname.  Need to filter the course record using category filter. category id is selecting properly. I need to filter by category name. dropdown list from table category and the filter to be done in course table.  Example : if $selected = 1 then $selectedcat="Information Technology" then pass it to the query. This way it works. But I need to filter using the category directly.

```
<?php
    include('header-basic-light.php');
    require_once('dbconnect.php');

    $selsql="SELECT catno,catname FROM category";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$selsql);
    if ($res == '')
    {
        echo "No connection";
        die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $selected=0;
    if (isset($_POST['categories']))
    {
    $selected=$_POST['categories']; 
    //echo $selected;
    }


    $selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses";
    $res1=(mysqli_query($con,$selectsql));

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$selectsql)) 
    {
    die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if ($selected==1) 
    {
    $selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";
    $res1=(mysqli_query($con,$selectsql));
    }
    else
    if ($selected==2) 
    {
    $selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";
    $res1=(mysqli_query($con,$selectsql));
    }


    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Drop down list </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

    <label for="categories">Select the Category : </label>
        <select name="categories" style="width:250px;" onchange="this.form.submit();">

    <?php 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
      if($selected==$row['catno']) {
        $selectedcat= $row['catname'];
        /* here you can get $selectedcat*/
      }
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['catno'];?>"
      <?php 
        if($selected == $row['catno']) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } 
      ?> 
      >
      <?php echo $row['catname'];?>
      </option>
    <?php } ?>
        </select>
     </form>
    <h2>View Information</h2>
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>cname</th>
    <th>start_date</th>
    <th>duration</th>
    <th>Remarks</th>
    <th>Options</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1))
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $r['cno'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['cname'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['start_date'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['duration'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['remarks'];?></td>
    <?php if ($r['ccategory']=='Information Technology') {$catnum=1;}
    if ($r['ccategory']=='Management') {$catnum=2;} ?>
    <td><a href="loadpage.php?id=<?php echo $catnum;?>">Details&nbsp&nbsp</a>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: what value hold in this variable $selected

Comment: `if ($selected==1) 
    {
    $selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";
    $res1=(mysqli_query($con,$selectsql));
    }
    else
    if ($selected==2) 
    {
    $selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";
    $res1=(mysqli_query($con,$selectsql));
    }` is completely redundant duplication. The code is identical no matter the value of $selected. And $selectedcat is not defined, so you will likely get no results. Before that you run a query to select all courses, regardless of the value of $selected, which seems wasteful.

Comment: Added to that, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL like that.

Comment: In summary, your logic is a complete mess and needs a rethink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
<?php 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  if($selected==$row['catno']) {
    $selectedcat= $row['catname'];
    /* here you can get $selectedcat*/
  }
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['catno'];?>"
  <?php 
    if($selected == $row['catno']) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } 
  ?> 
  >
  <?php echo $row['catname'];?>
  </option>
```

and please see updated answer and you should not close mysqli connection before any mysqli instruction.
so use `mysqli_close($con);` at the bottom of page or after you used all mysqli instruction in code

```
<?php
   include('header-basic-light.php');
   require_once('dbconnect.php');

   $selsql="SELECT catno,catname FROM category";
   $res=mysqli_query($con,$selsql);
   if ($res == '')
   {
       echo "No connection";
       die(mysqli_error($con));
   }
$selected=0;
if (isset($_POST['categories']))
{
   $selected=$_POST['categories']; 
   //echo $selected;
}


$selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses";
$res1 = mysqli_query($con,$selectsql);

if (!mysqli_query($con,$selectsql)) 
{
   die(mysqli_error($con));
}
if ($selected != 0) 
{
  /* fetch $selectedcat  from input hidden name hid_selected_cat_name*/
   $selectedcat = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($_POST['hid_selected_cat_name'])); 
   $selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";
   $res1=mysqli_query($con,$selectsql);
}


?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drop down list </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

<label for="categories">Select the Category : </label>
    <select name="categories" style="width:250px;" onchange="this.form.submit();">

<?php 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  if($selected==$row['catno']) {
    $selectedcat= $row['catname'];
    /* here you can get $selectedcat*/
  }
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['catno'];?>"
  <?php 
    if($selected == $row['catno']) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } 
  ?> 
  >
  <?php echo $row['catname'];?>
  </option>
<?php } ?>
    </select>

    /* store $selectedcat into hidden id*/
    <input type="hidden" id="hid_selected_cat_name" name="hid_selected_cat_name" value="<?php echo $selectedcat;?>" >

 </form>
<h2>View Information</h2>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>cname</th>
<th>start_date</th>
<th>duration</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
<th>Options</th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $r['cno'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $r['cname'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $r['start_date'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $r['duration'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $r['remarks'];?></td>
<?php if ($r['ccategory']=='Information Technology') {$catnum=1;}
if ($r['ccategory']=='Management') {$catnum=2;} ?>
<td><a href="loadpage.php?id=<?php echo $catnum;?>">Details&nbsp&nbsp</a>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to store $row['catname'] in to a variable like catno is stored in $selected.

Comment: @yesganesh "like catno is stored in $selected." catno is _not_ stored in $selected in this code. == does a comparison, not an assignment. Which makes sense, because it's within an `if`. But from this code and yours, we cannot see what value $selected has to begin with.

Comment: please try my new answer @yesganesh

Comment: please tick my answer if my answer solve your problem @yesganesh

Comment: I have changed the code. But still I am unable to filter the records according to the category name field. Can I send the full code.

Comment: Sorry. Still the same. Thanks for the support not filtering . I have removed the close statement.

Comment: where r u using `$selectedcat`

Comment: i want to ask where you want to use `$selectedcat` in code as you have not used `$selectedcat`  after assigning value to  `$selectedcat`

Comment: if ($selected != 0) 
{
   $selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";
   $res1=mysqli_query($con,$selectsql);
}

Comment: Before this statement so that the value of  $selectedcat will be available to pass in the query

Comment: u can do this by saving `$selectedcat` into hidden id and then fetch after form submit as i have done in my answer @yesganesh

Comment: Now its filtering . But for Information technology it shows management filtered records and for management it showsrecord information management

Comment: if you select management it shows(filters) information technology records

Comment: if you want to show filtered category which user is selected then in  form submit code  use selected category id to fetch category name from category table

Comment: then use fetched category name in `$selectsql="SELECT * FROM courses where ccategory='$selectedcat'";` in this sql

Answer (score 0):

simple one.  try this.

```
<?php    
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
 $selectedFlag = ($selected==$row['catno']) ? "selected" : "";
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['catno'];?>" <?php echo $selectedFlag ?> >  
  <?php echo $selectedcat= $row['catname'];?>
</option> 
<?php } ?>
```